# OCR not working when background color & text color almost similar

Tags: android, ocr, google-cloud-vision, abbyy

We are facing one issue when we try to scan bag. The main reason behind that the text color on the bag which are embroidered are almost same as bag's color. So it can not scan exact text which is written on the bag.

To get actual idea I have attached image.

In attached image we want to scan bag's id (D1 150491). Let me know if we have to do extra effort to scan this type of image.

**Note: We have tried two SDK**

- [Google Vision Api](https://cloud.google.com/vision/)
- [Abbyy](https://rtrsdk.com/)

[image]

Comment: Hi,

You need to preprocess your image before finally sending it to do some OCR work. you can change threshold , b/w etc or apply some filters it will help you find text more clearly to do OCR.

Comment: it is just to hard for OCR to see the letters here.

Comment: Lack of contrast.  Need to achieve character edge separation from the background through binarization and various image pre-processing filters.  I agree, very tough - I have no advice without prolonged experimentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been suggested in the comments to your question, there is not really much that can be done besides pre-processing your image. Google Cloud Vision API (and probably all other OCR platforms out there) will not be able to recognize a text such as the one you present in this image.

In order to improve the recognition for images such as this one, you should apply some pre-processing techniques, among which you could consider (but not limited to) the ones mentioned in the comments:

- **Applying filters:** edge detection, using some of the popular methods such as Canny or Sobel (have some examples [here](https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/edge-detection.html)).
- **Image binarization:** consists in setting a threshold in the gray level of the image, in such a way that the background has one colour (either white or black) and the letters have another. You can have a look at some examples [here](http://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/projects/image/glt/binar.html), although I do not think this will work for your case, as the gray level of the letters and the rest of the image seems quite similar (only a little bit of brightness in the letters due to its volume).
- **Play around:** change the brightness and contrast of the image, and you might be able to get some results. However, this process is difficult to automate, and the same values will probably not work for different images.

In short, there is no easy way to do this, and you will have to pre-process the images in order to get something that can actually be understood by the models behind the Vision API.

Answer (score 0):

This image is of captcha-level difficulty -- you can't ask not a pre-trained model to recognize it.

Seems like these characters have a relief -- If I had these bag in my hands I would look for a way to make a shot of this physically, like putting a bag into wet sand. Also you are lucky if you know beforehead what are possible formats and symbols on each position.

Answer (score 0):

My task different - detecting very tiny serial numbers engraved on metalic surface. What helped me the most in my case are basically two things:
1. Making the photo with a mobile and a its LED switched on. Increases contrast heavily.
2. Using CLAHE (Google it) as additional contrast enhancement. It significantly helps Google Vision OCR recognition.